# Prove that A ⊂ B → (A ∪ C) ⊂ (B ∪ C).

Tags: logic, proof-writing, solution-verification

I am a little stuck on this problem.  I think I am missing a few steps in my proof cause my logic does not fully follow.  Any help would be appreciated.

Prove that A ⊂ B → (A ∪ C) ⊂ (B ∪ C).

(A ∪ C) ⊂ (B ∪ C)

(∀x){x ∈ (A ∪ C) → x ∈ (B ∪ C)}

{x ∈ (A ∪ C) → x ∈ (B ∪ C)}

[x ∈ {x|x  ∈ A ^x ∈ C} → {x |x  ∈ C ^x ∈ C}]

....

True. Q.E.D

Comment: Let $x\in A\cup C$. If $x\in C$ then clear and if $x\in A$ then by assumption, clear.

Comment: Can you please reformat your question to make it clear? Use mathjax to write mathematical expressions, here is a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: You are making two basic mistakes in your approach to proofs.  First, you seem to be starting with the statement you are trying to prove and trying to reduce it somehow to "true".  This is backwards.  The statement you are trying to prove is what you should end with, not what you should start with.  Second, your attempted proof is just a list of symbolic expressions.  That's a bad idea.  A proof should be an essay written in complete sentences, not just symbols.

Comment: In this case, your proof should have the following outline:  "Assume that $A \subset B$.  Let $x$ be arbitrary, and assume that $x \in A \cup C$.  [Now write some sentences explaining why it must be the case that $x \in B \cup C$.]  Since $x$ was arbitrary, we can conclude that $\forall x(x \in A \cup C \to x \in B \cup C)$.  Therefore $A \cup C \subset B \cup C$."  Notice that the proof _ends_ with the conclusion you are trying to prove, it doesn't start there.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $A \subset B$.  In this way,
\begin{eqnarray}
 x \in A \cup C & \Rightarrow & x \in A \ \mbox{or} \ x \in C\\
 & \Rightarrow & x \in B \ \mbox{or} \ x \in C\\
 & \Rightarrow & x \in B \cup C,
 \end{eqnarray}
which proves $A \cup C \subset B \cup C$.